# Adding 3 div in main div loop

Tags: php, html, css

I want to add 3 `<div class="cols">` block in main `<div class="rows">` loop.
I get data from `DB` and formating to 3 `<div class="cols">` cals and `<div class="rows">` rows.

I need like following :

```
<div class="rows">
    <div class="cols"></div>
    <div class="cols"></div>
    <div class="cols"></div>
</div>
<div class="rows">
    <div class="cols"></div>
    <div class="cols"></div>
    <div class="cols"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cols"></div>
    <div class="cols"></div>
    <!-- if total record is 8 then display only 2 divs -->
</div>
```

So what I write in loop to make it dynamically?

Comment: Show your loop if you have tried it

Comment: i try while loop... but it worth lees..so nothing try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this :

```
$data = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'); //you get from database

$cnt = 1;
foreach ($data as $dt) {
    if ($cnt%3 == 1) {
        echo "<div class='rows'>";
    }
    echo "<div class='cols'>";
    echo $dt;
    echo "</div>"; //close "class=cols" div
    if ($cnt % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</div>"; //close "class=rows" div
    }
    $cnt++;
}
if ($cnt%3 != 1)
{
    echo "</div>"; //close "class=rows" div
}
```

Comment: `if ($cnt % 2 == 0) {echo "</div>"; //close "class=rows" div}`: really? When `$cnt` will be 4, you close the parent div but you need to close that later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested

```html
<?php foreach($rows as $row){?>
<div class = "rows">
    <?php foreach($row['cols'] as $col){?>
    <div class = "cols"></div>
    <? }?>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have data from database, you probably use `while` loop and you just need to count and remember the current iterate.

Here is the code which could work, I didn't test that. At least the main point how to do it is there.

PS. this code expects you don't have nested array and just X records from databse in one array.

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $i++;

    echo $i % 3 == 1 ? '<div class="rows">' : ''; // open .rows div during the first, fourth, etc. loop

    echo '<div class="cols">' . $row['data'] . '</div>'; // write data

    echo $i % 3 == 0 ? '</div>' : ''; // close .rows div in the third, sixth, etc. loop
}

if ($i % 3 != 0) {
    echo '</div>'; // if the last iteration didn't close the .rows div, close that now
}
```

If you will have nested arrays, the solution will be clearer.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo '<div class="rows">';

    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo '<div class="cols">' . $item .' </div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        ?>
        <div class = "rows">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class = "cols"></div>
        <div class = "cols"></div>
        <div class = "cols"></div>
        <?php
        if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query('your query');
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$i = 3;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        echo '<div class="rows">';
    }
    echo '<div class="cols">Your data</div>';
    $i++;
}
if($i % 3 == 0){
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```